# Minting gas price too high

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, rinkeby, mint

I am trying to test a minting function in a smart contract deployed on rinkeby and i was wondering why is the gas price so high for minting, is there any way to reduce the gas price ?

[image: cost in gas for the transaction of minting 2 tokens]

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
contract owned {
    address public owner;
constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }
contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 2;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;
// This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    
    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);
/**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }
/**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }
/**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }
/**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }
/**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}

contract cryptealo is owned, TokenERC20 {
uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;
mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
/* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);
/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}
/* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);               // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }
/// @notice Create `mintedAmount` tokens and send it to `target`
    /// @param target Address to receive the tokens
    /// @param mintedAmount the amount of tokens it will receive
    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner public {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        emit Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        emit Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }
    /// @notice `freeze? Prevent | Allow` `target` from sending & receiving tokens
    /// @param target Address to be frozen
    /// @param freeze either to freeze it or not
    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }
    /// @notice Allow users to buy tokens for `newBuyPrice` eth and sell tokens for `newSellPrice` eth
    /// @param newSellPrice Price the users can sell to the contract
    /// @param newBuyPrice Price users can buy from the contract
    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner public {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }
/// @notice Buy tokens from contract by sending ether
    function buy() payable public {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;               // calculates the amount
        _transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);              // makes the transfers
    }
/// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
    /// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
    function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        address myAddress = this;
        require(myAddress.balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
        _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
        msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The gas is way high. It's something not seen even on Mainnet.

You need to post your smart contract code to to see if there is a bug or check by yourself!

Or try it out on local ganache network

Comment: thank you, i tried checking my code, but found nothing wrong, maybe because im not that good at solidity yet, i also tried checking in local ganache network but din't encounter that problem. but i edited my post to add the code.

Comment: In local network check the gas incurred. The code may execute but gas could be very high

Answer (score 1):

I deployed your contracts on my local ganache-cli. And the "cost" was `883 020 gas`. How much ETH that would be depends on the gas price. But even if you were paying `100 gwei` the final price would be --> `100 x 883 020 = 8,830,2000 gwei`.

What would be equal to `0.088302 ETH` (Nowhere near what you got). The only logical explanation I can think of is if you had accidentally set gas price to `8k gwei`. Or there is something very wrong in your deployment script and you are not deploying what you think you are.

Comment: yes thank you for the information, i also deployed the same contract in ganache and did not get a high amount, when i tried using the minting function. and yea im deploying the exact same code i posted, i did it on rinkeby testnet, and when i try to mint i get the high price, i din't even set a gas price , i just set the limit to 3000000000 gas.

Comment: Ah, so you get that insane gas price when you try to mint token? Not during contract deployment?

Comment: yes, for deployment i get the gas price of 1130526, it is only when i try to mint tokens, because i was testing every function from my smart contract to see if its working as intented so far my only problem is the minting function costing way to much. to my knowledge minting is creating more quanity of the token i created. so the scenario im testing is: deploy a smart contrat with amount of 100 then i transfer the 100 to my second wallet, and then i try my minting function and try to mint any amount.

Answer (score 0):

When i was working on smart contract and i deploy it on theta_mainnet it and interacting with smart contract in nextjs using web3 i face this issue then i convert my interacting code from web3 to etherjs library then it works fine you can try this.